# about git and wsl usage safety

Tags: git, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am experimenting **wsl** (ubuntu) and **x410** server to work with **intellij** idea in linux as I have to use a win10 machine :P
I was wondering if it's safe to open from idea a project located into 
`/mnt/c/Users/_username/git/_project` 
could this scenario could be a problem because
`git` installed in ubuntu had to keep track of changes located into ntfs via mount point

> the other option is to use work locally but this is better as I can repen the same solution with idea in win10 so I can work and run test on both on the same changes

[image]

Comment: Can you punctuate your question properly?

Comment: " because git installed in ubuntu had to keep track of changes located into ntfs via mount point" What do you mean by this?

Comment: assuming you have in win c:\something\git when you are in wls you can see it mapped as /mn/c/something/git -git tracks changes based on the fs - if you change files inside wls you might have problem when you want to commit them because they actually changed in ntfs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the same repository with Windows programs and under WSL; I do this whenever I must use a Windows machine for some reason.  However, there are some issues you may run into.

First, you want to avoid using alternates (so don't use `git clone -s`), because this embeds a path name into your repository, and it will of course differ between Windows and WSL.

Second, Git for Windows stores different data in the index than the emulated Linux environment.  You may end up needing to set `core.checkStat` to `minimal` and `core.trustctime` to `false` if files frequently appear modified between the two.  If they don't, then there's no need to set that.

Finally, a symbolic link created in one environment will look modified when `git status` is run in the other, because the size of a symlink on Windows is a whole block and on Linux it is the length of the filename.  The size is stored in Git's index, and will be updated whenever the index is updated; there's no way to avoid this.

Other than that, usually this works fine.  You may find that you can't modify or check out a file that is open in Windows; that's because Windows doesn't allow replacing files that are in use by a Win32 program, regardless of whether this is fine in Linux.  This is a limitation on Windows that you just have to deal with if you use Windows.